# Optimally reducing maximum flow

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a parameter *k*, I'm trying to delete *k* edges from a directed graph such that the maximum flow is reduced by as much as possible. The graph has a source *s* and a sink *t*, and the capacity of each edge is one. The graph may or may not contain cycles.

My proposed solution would be to first perform a topological sorting on the graph, using an algorithm that "forgives" cycles -- perhaps by ignoring edges that lead us back to the source. Then (assuming *k* >= 1):

```
i = 0
for each vertex u order by topological(u)
   for each edge (u, v) order by topological(v) descending
       if topological(v) > topological(u) then
            delete (u, v)
            if ++i = k then return
       else
            // edge doesn't contribute to max flow, ignore
```

Would this work, or am I totally off-track here?

Comment: "Finding the minimum cut" can be achieved by algorithms that can find the "maximum flow" such as the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. But what exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean with reducing the maximum flow?

Comment: @Christian: The idea is that we've already found a max flow using an algorithm such as Ford-Fulkerson, but now we want to strategically delete k edges so that we can reduce it by as much as possible.

Comment: Well, I remember answering this exact question in my computer science course last year, I just don't remember what I answered haha :P IIRC the max flow algorithm partitions the graph into 2 sets A, B such that the flow along the edges from A to B is at capacity, meaning that those edges are the "choke point" (in military terminology) of the flow. If you cut those edges you will most definitely be reduces the total flow by the most amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are totally off-track. Your algorithm might not reduce the flow at all, while it is possible to reduce the max flow by at least k (or make it 0).

Do you know the max-flow min-cut theorem?

Comment: I know it in that I've memorized "the maximum value of an s-t flow is equal to the minimum capacity that must be removed so that no flow can go from s to t," but it's not immediately clear to me how that will help me in this situation. Do we want to find s-t cuts in the graph and take away edges that cross the cut?

Comment: @Arlck: I suggest you try to answer that question yourself.